# Recursively Gziping Files (and keep original files) & Gziping Text Input

Tags: command-line, gzip

I need Gzip to pre-zip some static files for a webserver I'm building. All of the files I need to gzip will be in a folder named `.cache`. Since some clients may not accept responses that are gzipped, I would like to keep all of the original files when I gzip them. Is there any command I can use to recursively gzip the files in my `.cache` folder while still keeping the original files? Will this command gzip gzipped files (ones that are postfixed with .gz already) if run on a folder with already gzipped files?

While we're on the topic of gzip: I've been looking for a way to gzip text input passed to gzip  instead of files. I came up with postfixing a dash on the command (like `gzip -c -`), but I'm not sure if that will work or how I use it. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the option `-c` to output the result to `stdout`. `gzip`ing all files in `.cache`:

```
for i in .cache/*; do gzip -c "$i" > "$i.gz"; done
```

**EDIT:**
To `gzip` them again and not `gzip` the `gzip`ed files check the suffix:

```
for i in .cache/*; do [ "${i:(-3)}" == ".gz" ] || gzip -c "$i" > "$i.gz"; done
```

So only files that not end in `.gz` will be `gzip`ed.

Comment: Thanks! What about passing text to gzip? Can gzip only work its magic on files or can you pass it a string?

Comment: What do you mean with text? Of course you can also do the following: `echo word | gzip -c > test.gz`. `test.gz` will contain the `gzip`ed `word`.

Comment: I'll just do it that way...